# How seriously is the hedonic treadmill taken among psychologists?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

To me the notion seems somewhat counter intuitive to suggest a person who lives a normal life, is then placed in a situation where for example theyre subjected to constant abuse and fear, would adapt to have the same base level of happiness in both situations.

Therefore, I was wondering if professionals use it as more of guideline or if it is taken at face value to mean humans will always return to a baseline of happiness.

I found a paper that listed some situations where people supposedly don't return to a baseline happiness, although they seem quite specific.

> In a 19-year
> investigation of representative German residents, Lucas ( 2007b )
> found that those who had experienced a government-certifi ed
> disability during the course of the study showed a signifi cant and
> sustained drop in their level of wellbeing from before to after the
> onset of disability, even after income and employment were controlled.
> Participants from the same data set who were followed up from 15 to 18
> years reported signifi cantly reduced well-being years after becoming
> unemployed (Lucas, Clark, Georgellis, & Diener, 2004 ), divorced
> (Lucas, 2005 ), and widowed (Lucas, Clark, Georgellis, & Diener, 2003
> ). Notably, in all these studies, whether individuals had experienced
> disability, unemployment, widowhood, or divorce (all extremely
> negative experiences in the domains of health, work, and interpersonal
> relationships), their levels of well-being took a “hit” from the event
> and, on average, never fully recovered.

http://sonjalyubomirsky.com/files/2012/09/Lyubomirsky-2011.pdf

Comment: Related: [What can one do to permanently increase one's baseline happiness (subjective well-being)?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/23588/7001)